# How To make Auto Number in sql server with combination Year month

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

i want to make auto number in sql server like this

BK/201304/0002

BK : Just Inisialisation 
2013 : is a year 
04 : Month
0002 : is increament and back again if the month is change

thanks

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: What is Inisialisation?

Comment: i do this for make aplication in form vb.net, and BK it mean the name of form vb.net

Comment: Welcome to SO. Start with real words?  -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below assumes that you have a sequence table already. A sequence or number table is just a (one column) table with incrementing numbers.

```
select 'BK/' 
    + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)
    + right('00' + cast(month(getdate()) as varchar), 2)
    + '/'
    + right('0000' + cast(isnull((select max(Seq) + 1 from SequenceTable), 0) as varchar), 4)
```

Please let me know if you don't already have one. I will update my answer to include one for you.

UPDATE - Included code for the SequenceTable.

```
create table SequenceTable
(
    Seq int not null identity(1, 1)
)

create proc dbo.IncrementSeq
as
set nocount on

if day(getdate()) = 1
    truncate table SequenceTable -- Reset
else
    insert SequenceTable default values -- Increment 

return 0
go
```

I am starting to make a lot of assumptions which makes me very uncomfortable. The code above assumes that you can call a stored procedure before generating your auto sequence number. If that's the case, you can even include all my code in the stored procedure as a single step. See code below:

```
create proc dbo.IncrementSeq
as
set nocount on

if day(getdate()) = 1
    truncate table SequenceTable -- Reset
else
    insert SequenceTable default values -- Increment 

select 'BK/' 
    + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)
    + right('00' + cast(month(getdate()) as varchar), 2)
    + '/'
    + right('0000' + cast(isnull((select max(Seq) + 1 from SequenceTable), 0) as varchar), 4)

return 0
go
```

UPDATE - I have improved my answer for completeness and simplicity.

```
create table SequenceTable
(
    Seq varchar(max) not null 
)

insert SequenceTable
select 'BK/' 
    + cast(year(Getdate()) as varchar) 
    + right('00' + cast(month(getdate()) as varchar), 2) 
    + '/' 
    + case when day(getdate()) = 1 then '0000'
        else right('0000' + cast(isnull((select right(max(Seq), 4) + 1 from SequenceTable), 0) as varchar), 4)
    end
```

Comment: i don't have sequence table

Comment: I do not have a table autonumber increament, because if there is increment field that he will still count the deleted was deleted.
im use sql server 2005

Comment: So do you need one created, or you don't think it will solve your problem?

Comment: The results of the query would I put in a field, do you know how to make the field had become increament, by cutting 4 last sequence and to locate and re-add to its max value of max was

Comment: Here i get.. THanks a lot for help Louie Bao<br />

select 'BN/'
 + cast(year(Getdate()) as varchar(4))
 + right ('00' + cast(month(getdate()) as varchar ),(2))
 +'/'
 + right ('0000' + cast((select max(Substring (seq,11,4)) + 1 from SequenceTable) as varchar), 4)

Comment: Hei Loiu Bao 
how to make That field gone be set 1 agian if the month is change ?

Comment: case day(getdate()) = 1 then '0000' else ... end

Comment: You will need to move your substring() outside max().

Comment: where i must write Louie Bao, Can you combine the code that I wrote